# initialize QTMovie for file dropped in NSTableview

Tags: objective-c

Guys, I'm just lerning Objective C and writing software for table where I drag mp3 files and want to access their metadata and display artist, genre and etc. So I have class for "drag and drop" and class for "access metadata". 
I think problem is I don't know how to initialize QTMovie for file I dropped from finder to table.

here is line of code:

movie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:@"/* so, what i should write here??*/" error:nil];

thanks,
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your question is just "How do I get a file from drag-and-drop?" Once you know how to get the dropped file, you just pass it into your mystery string. The short answer is that you implement the NSDraggingDestination protocol and in your `performDragOperation:` method, you ask the drag info object for its `propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType`.

There's a whole [drag-and-drop guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069-SW1) on Apple's website that includes lots of detailed instructions and example code.